Labview Power Supply Control Through TCP and QMH
I'm a newbie in LV and to practice I'm controlling a power supply (TTI) with labview. Requirements are really easy. All I have to do is creating the first channel of the supply. There'll be three main buttons SET, OUTPUT and STOP. SET button will set the voltage and current values that the user wrote; OUTPUT button will open the OUTPUT of the channel 1 and STOP button will stop the code and close the power. The communication through supply and LV will be over TCP protocol.
I've decided to use Queued message handler and created two different loops, the event handling loop and the message handling loop. For event handling loop, I've created an event structure for the three buttons that I've mentioned above. I think I've handled this part pretty good however for the message handling loop I've some problems. I've created a case structure and cases are here:

Init -> I'll be initializing variables and it'll lead to the open connection case

Open Connection -> In this case I'm opening the TCP connection, also created a constant to store the ID

Set Values -> I have to send the set value command that I've created in the event handling loop

Output -> I have to open the output channel of the power supply

Measure/Display -> I have to show the current Voltage and current values of the supply, it has ta be done in every 200 ms

Stop -> I have to stop the program and close the output of the supply, also release the queue
The problem that I have is that I can't figure out how to combine these cases with TCP, I've done the Init and Open Connection parts and a little bit of Set Values, however I don't know how my approach should be.

How am I supposed to measure and display the current values in every 200 ms with TCP?

How can I parse the response of the commands that I sent over TCP?
Please don't forget that I'm a newbie and there're too many things that I don't know.



Concerning the parsing you can have a look in the TCP/IP example:
labview\examples\Data Communication\Protocols\TCP\Simple TCP\Simple TCP.lvproj
Basically you will compute the size of the package and send that information first, then the actual package:

Regarding the reading at 200ms one solution would be to put a timeout in your event loop of 200ms. Just keep in mind that if you are running your software on Windows (which is not a real time OS) you might (or will) have some jitter, i.e. it might be every 200 ms +-1ms.
For the updating of the indicators, if you put them directly in the reading state then it will be easy to update them. Otherwise you can store the last read value in a shift register and read that value to update your indicators.
I hope this answer your questions,
Thomas
Certified LabVIEW Architect

Thank you for the answer Thomas, I'll be checking :)
